# How to set GeoJSONSource from a stored value in mapbox-ios swift?

Tags: swift, mapbox-ios

I am using mapbox-ios and I am having trouble setting the source data component of a GeoJSONSource

in Android this is achieved with the GeoJSONSource.Builder

```
delegate.addSource(GeoJsonSource.Builder(ID).data(str).attribution(layer.State).build())
```

in Swift a live url (which delivers a geojson object) works fine, however taking the same

```
var source =   GeoJSONSource ()
    
source.data = .url(URL (string: layer.url)!)  //  live, this works fine
```

However I am unable to set the GeoJSONSource (jsonObect: validgeoJSONObject)

```
 let jsonObject =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: layer.data.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? String ("{}}").data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!) as! [String: Any]


let source =  try GeoJSONSource (jsonObject: jsonObject)
```

this always throws an exception saying the json object is invalid

```
"Cannot initialize SourceType from invalid String value FeatureCollection"
```

Can someone show me the proper way of setting the GeoJSONSource from a stored value rather than from a URL?

Comment: I found though the mapbox source that it is expecting another json container with a "data" property pointing to the geojson source and a type = "geojson". Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

GeoJSONSourceData can also be an inlined geojson string as shown in this [LargeGeoJSONExample](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-ios/blob/main/Apps/Examples/Examples/All%20Examples/LargeGeoJSONExample.swift)

In your case I'd guess `layer.data`is a valid geojson string, you can do

```
var source = GeoJSONSource(id: "source-id")
source.data = .string(layer.data)
```